# How to change_column in Rails from string to jsonb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I tried to write a migration for an existing column in Rails 5.0.2:

```
def up
  change_column(:sales_deals, :lost_reason, 'jsonb USING CAST(lost_reason AS jsonb)')
end

def down
  change_column(:sales_deals, :lost_reason, 'string USING CAST(lost_reason AS string)')
end
```

However, failed to `CAST` existing string to jsonb:

```
PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR: invalid input syntax for type json
DETAIL: Token "Non" is invalid.
CONTEXT:  JSON data, line 1: Non...
: ALTER TABLE "sales_deals" ALTER COLUMN "lost_reason" TYPE jsonb USING CAST(lost_reason AS jsonb)
```

---

My guess is there are two problems:

1) I need to specify type of the value, because the token "Non" is a beginning of a string with hyphen, "Non-commutative".

2) I need to define a default key, because of the existing values.

Can anyone help please? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should try as follow:

```
  def up
    change_column :sales_deals, :lost_reason, :jsonb, using: 'CAST(value AS JSON)'
  end

  def down
    change_column :sales_deals, :lost_reason, :text
  end
```

That's it.

Comment: Your solution worked for some, but at the end migration cancelled and got this error:


```PG::CannotCoerce: ERROR:  cannot cast type numeric to jsonb
LINE 1: ...eals" ALTER COLUMN "lost_reason" TYPE jsonb USING CAST(value...
                                                             ^
: ALTER TABLE "sales_deals" ALTER COLUMN "lost_reason" TYPE jsonb USING CAST(value AS jsonb)```

Comment: you can try the same with: "using: 'notes::JSON'" i.e. replace the "using" area in first line and then try